# Executing a PyQt5 GUI which includes subprocesses from the Linux terminal causes a black screen in the GUI and freezes it

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, pyqt5

First, I would like to show you what works so far. Below is a simple GUI built with the same principles as the one that causes problems. It has a button and when you click it a counter increases.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initGUI()
        self.behaviours()

        self.counter = 0

    def initGUI(self):
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.box.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(self.box)
        self.show()

    def behaviours(self):
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def add(self):
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.counter))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = GUI()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am able to execute the script from the Linux terminal with the following command:

```
python3 TestGUI.py
```

The GUI opens as intended and I can interact with the button.

As soon as a subprocess gets included in the script, like the one below, the GUI does still open but it is completely black and non-responsive.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("onedrive", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
(output, err) = p1.communicate()
```

I think that there is a problem when you use the terminal to execute a python script which itself executes commands in the terminal.

Do you have any idea on how this problem can be solved?

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Popen since the [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method is blocking, instead use [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initGUI()
        self.behaviours()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.button)
        box.addWidget(self.label)

        self.show()

    def behaviours(self):
        self._onedrive_process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._onedrive_process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self._onedrive_process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(
            self.on_readyReadStandardOutput
        )
        self._onedrive_process.setProgram("onedrive")

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_onedrive)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def connect_to_onedrive(self):
        self._onedrive_process.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        result = self._onedrive_process.readAllStandardOutput()
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

If you want to pass options to the command you must use [`setArguments()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setArguments):

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class OneDriveManager(QtCore.QObject):
    logChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.on_readyReadStandardOutput)
        self._process.setProgram("onedrive")

    def launch(self, options=None):
        self._process.setArguments(options)
        if self._process.state() != QtCore.QProcess.NotRunning:
            self._process.kill()
        self._process.start()

    def help(self):
        self.launch(["--help"])

    def synchronize(self):
        self.launch(["--synchronize"])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        res = self._process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.logChanged.emit(res)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._onedrive_manager = OneDriveManager(self)

        help_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Help")
        help_button.clicked.connect(self._onedrive_manager.help)

        synchronize_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Synchronize")
        synchronize_button.clicked.connect(self._onedrive_manager.synchronize)

        log_plaintextedit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self._onedrive_manager.logChanged.connect(log_plaintextedit.setPlainText)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(help_button)
        lay.addWidget(synchronize_button)
        lay.addWidget(log_plaintextedit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: After trying this it worked, but sadly there is still another problem. It seems like I am not able to expand the command from "onedrive" to for example "onedrive --synchronize" or "onedrive --help". There was no result printed when trying this, even though there appears some return text in the terminal. So I am not able to insert longer commands there. After a little research it seems like that the QProcess has difficulties with the terminal syntax of more complicated commands. Is there a way I can execute commands like "onedrive --synchronize"?

Comment: @PascalAigner I don't know why you point out: *After a little research it seems like that the QProcess has difficulties with the terminal syntax of more complicated commands*, could you tell me what you used to draw that conclusion? If you affirm anything the minimum is to point out the evidence that support your statement. If you want to pass the command options you must use setArguments() or pass it as a list in the second argument of start: `process.start("onedrive", ["help"])`, I have added an example in my response.

Comment: Sorry, if my comment above was unclear. What I found is that with `setProgram("onedrive", ["--help"])` I received the error that there were too much arguments used in `setProgram`. But as you pointed out, if I pass these arguments to the `process.start` as you did in your comment above it works. Thank you very much for your support.